# How to use gson deserialize to ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I use this class to store data

```
public class Item(var name:String,
                  var description:String?=null){
}
```

And use it in ArrayList

```
public var itemList = ArrayList<Item>()
```

Use this code to serialize the object

```
val gs=Gson()
val itemListJsonString = gs.toJson(itemList)
```

And deserialize

```
itemList = gs.fromJson<ArrayList<Item>>(itemListJsonString, ArrayList::class.java)
```

But this method will give me `LinkedTreeMap`, not `Item`, I cannot cast LinkedTreeMap to Item

What is correct way to deserialize to json in Kotlin?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this code for deserialize list

```
val gson = Gson()
val itemType = object : TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.type
itemList = gson.fromJson<List<Item>>(itemListJsonString, itemType)
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Could you please explain your answer, like how you come up with the second line? I'm new to Kotlin (and Java) and this construct is not so familiar to me. For example, why couldn't you just have the second argument be something like <List<Item>>.class ?

Comment: @Zagfai Well then, if you don't know what you are deserializing use `Any`, or deserialize as List<Map>. If you don't know the target data structure, it will not be better in any other language.

Answer (score 10):

You can define a inline reified extension function like:

```
internal inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String) =
    fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```

And use it like:

```
val itemList: List<Item> = gson.fromJson(itemListJsonString)
```

By default, types are erased at runtime, so Gson cannot know which kind of `List` it has to deserialize. However, when you declare the type as `reified` you preserve it at runtime. So now Gson has enough information to deserialize the `List` (or any other generic Object).

Answer (score 2):

In my code I just use:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
Gson().fromJson(string_var, Array<Item>::class.java).toList() as ArrayList<Type>
```

I give here a complete example.

First the type and the list array:

```
class Item(var name:String,
           var description:String?=null)
var itemList = ArrayList<Item>()
```

The main code:

```
itemList.add( Item("Ball","round stuff"))
itemList.add(Item("Box","parallelepiped stuff"))
val striJSON = Gson().toJson(itemList)  // To JSON
val backList  = Gson().fromJson(        // Back to another variable
       striJSON, Array<Item>::class.java).toList() as ArrayList<Item>
val striJSONBack = Gson().toJson(backList)  // To JSON again
if (striJSON==striJSONBack)   println("***ok***")
```

The exit:

```
***OK***
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the accepted answer (that works but creates an object to get its type), you could just do:

```
val gson = Gson()
itemList = gson.fromJson(itemListJsonString, Array<Item>::class.java)
```

There "Array" represents a Java array when targeting the JVM platform. That's not an ArrayList but you can access the items (that's usually all is needed after parsing JSON).

If you still need to manipulate the list you could easily convert it to mutable by doing:

```
itemsList.toMutableList()
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be answered already, but for Kotlin as of April 2023, you can create this extension:

```
fun <T> Gson.fromJsonList(jsonString: String): List<T> =
    this.fromJson(jsonString, object: TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() { }.type)
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
val discountList: List<Discount> = Gson().fromJsonList<Discount>(jsonString)
```

Hope this helped someone :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner solution:

```
// Item is the Type of your own Class
val itemList: List<Item> = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>() {}.type)
```